# Matomo reporting ignores / filters url patterns

Tags: matomo

Matomo on premises: 4.15

MySQL version: 8.0.32

PHP version: 8.2.1

Running in Windows 2019

The site being monitored uses 3 kind of urls with ID:

- `https://app.mydomain.com/pl1_XXXXXX/contentTitle` : the content was first created on the leader of the app
- `https://app.mydomain.com/pr1_XXXXXX/contentTitle` : the content was first created on the first replica
- `https://app.mydomain.com/pr2_XXXXXX/contentTitle` : the content was first created on the second replica

XXXXXX is a sequential number.
The pl1 / pr1 / pr2 are unique and an id never changes.

When archiving / creating reports in Matomo, only contents containing `pr1_XXXXXX` are being analyzed and available. All others urls are not available event though they do exist in the database.

I invalidated several dates and recreated the reports but nothing changes.

```
php.exe "D:\Matomo\console" core:archive -vvv --force-idsites="2" --url=https://matomo.mydomain.com >>matomo-archive.log 2>>error-archive.log
```

It executes with no errors. Debug mode is of no help here.

Same if called from the api

Why is Matomo ignoring the datas ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: first replace square brackets with parentheses. Square are for single char matches. Now try changing the order of your arguments there and see if it makes the change. Remove the pr1 from the regex and see if it returns anything. Maybe your issue is that there are no other urls in the dataset at all.

Comment: ah ! no... it isn't a regex.. I only wrote it that way to simplify

Comment: I queried the database and there are data in the dataset.

Comment: but you're completely sure your regex is good? Like you have thoroughly tested it on regex101?

Comment: There is no regex in matomo configuration. I updated my question to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Do you you have page scope filter or site scope filter settings which would  exclude particular types of URLs from your reports?

Comment: nothing of sorts